# How to concat a string and a char in idris?

Tags: idris

I am trying to concatenate a String and a Char to produce a String in idris. This is the code

```
*Printf> :let e1 : String = "123"
*Printf> :let e2 : Char = 'f'
*Printf> :let e3 : String = e1 ++ pack [e2]
(input):1:9: When checking type of e3:
Can't disambiguate name: Prelude.List.::, Prelude.Stream.::, Data.Vect.::
(input):1:9:No type declaration for e3
*Printf>
```

I don't understand the error. What is the problem here? This is Idris 1

Comment: Idris 1 or Idris 2?

Comment: edited the question to add that

Comment: i don't know why the error, but `e1 ++ cast e2` works

Answer (score 0):

Check the types! You are trying to join two strings with `++`. Is there a function by that name with the appropriate type? From the error, you could infer that `++` is used with list-like structures – that's why it mentions `::`; that is probably involved in the definition of `++`, but the type-checker can't find a function of that name applying to strings.

Absent a more specific function, you need to unpack the string, concat the character at the end, and repack:

```
e3 = pack (unpack e1 ++ [e2])
```